# How prove this $\left[\frac{n}{\sqrt{3}}\right] +1\ge \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{3n^2-\frac{50}{9}}}$

Tags: inequality

> For any integer $n\ge 2$ ,Prove that: $\left[\frac{n}{\sqrt{3}}\right] +1\ge \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{3n^2-k}}$ .
>
> when $k=\dfrac{50}{9}$

This $k$ is folowing idea found it.

let  $n=2$,then we have
$$2\ge \dfrac{4}{\sqrt{12-k}}\Longrightarrow k\le 8$$

let
$n=4$ we have
$$2+1\ge\dfrac{16}{\sqrt{48-k}}\Longrightarrow k\le\dfrac{176}{9}$$
$n=5$,then we have
$$2+1\ge \dfrac{25}{\sqrt{27-k}}\Longrightarrow k\le\dfrac{50}{9}$$
let $n=6$,we have $k\le 27$

let $n=10$,then we have
$$6\ge\dfrac{100}{\sqrt{300-k}}\Longrightarrow k\le\dfrac{200}{9}$$

so I guess the maximum $k=\dfrac{50}{9}$,
I want use @achille hui idea to prove it,and I found his methods can't use for this stronger inequality $$\dfrac{n^2}{\sqrt{3n^2-\dfrac{50}{9}}}\ge\dfrac{n^2}{\sqrt{3n^2-5}}$$[simaler problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021166/how-prove-this-inequality-left-fracn-sqrt3-right1-fracn2-sqrt3n)

Comment: Sure you can. Since $\frac{n^2}{3q_n^2} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. You know there is a $N$ such that $2 \frac{n^2}{q_n^2} \ge \frac{50}{9}$ for all $n \ge N$. It is not hard to check $N = 45$ works. What remains is to verify the newer inequality works for $2 \le n \le 44$ by brute force.

Comment: And here's the brute force http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BFloor%28n%2Fsqrt%283%29%29%2B1.0-n%5E2%2Fsqrt%283n%5E2-50%2F9%29%2C+%7Bn%2C2%2C44%7D%5D&x=0&y=0&js=off